# Getting current WiFi SSID is always nil on Testflight

Tags: swift

I use to get my current WiFi SSID and display it in my app.

I have location permissions set to always, as well as the required Privacy info.plist values. I also have the Access WiFi Information capability added to my project. When I build the app from Xcode to my iPhone (not a simulator), it works fine, I can see my WiFi SSID. However, when I distribute the app through Testflight it no longer works, it is returning nothing.

Comment: "Below is the code", but where exactly?

Comment: Test it with an IPA to see if it works, then.  By the way, the word 'below' is not a noun.  "Below is the code" is not a grammatically-correct English expression.

Comment: Do you have any Solutions? Please help me